# Jekyll Syntax Highlighting Not Working - Classes Are Not Being Added

Tags: css, jekyll, kramdown, rouge

I cannot get syntax highlighting to work on my Jekyll-powered blog.

The development files can be found here: https://github.com/StevenXL/stevenxl.github.io.

As you can see, in my `_config.yml` file, I have the following:

```
markdown: kramdown

kramdown:
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

In my `css/custom.css` file, I am importing the CSS file to highlight the syntax with an @import command.

The actual CSS file for highlighting lives in `css/monokai.css`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This seems to work fine on my local preview when I run `jekyll serve` but not when I push the development files to GitHub.It doesn't seem to be adding the correct classes when built by GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue using the `monokai` highlighting css from the [jekyll-uno](https://github.com/joshgerdes/jekyll-uno) theme.

To solve the problem I had to update the CSS, using rouge itself is quite straightforward (taken from the [docs](https://github.com/jneen/rouge#css-theme-options)):

`rougify style monokai > css/monokai.css`

There are [other themes](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/#inline_theme-nil) available, too.

Answer (score 1):

For me this seemed to be a casing issue for my language hints.

Did not work:

> ``` SQL

Worked:

> ``` sql

Comment: The space between the two is key for > ``` sql

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [Jekyll highlight tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting)

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: That get some of the highlighting to work, but I guess I have to modify the monokai.css file to work with however the classes are being added. I want to use this simple method: http://sacha.me/articles/jekyll-rouge/